# Java - checking .txt for existing text across all lines

Tags: java, file, io, text-files, readline

Basically, I am looking to add to a .txt file depending on whether a certain line exist already or not.

I.e. add the line to the .txt file if it doesn't exist already.
Don't add the line to the .txt file if it exists.

Every line stands alone

E.g.

One

Two

Three

and not
One, Two, Three etc.

I was thinking of using readLine() but it seems that it defines the end of a line when there's a break, like there my lines have. The method doesn't take any arguments (e.g. line numbers) so I'm pretty short-handen :/.

Any he

Comment: How do you define the end of a line except by a break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, as you suggest, the [readLine()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine%28%29) method of [RandomAccessFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to read each line of the file, looking for the expected text.

From the javadoc for readLine():

> A line of text is terminated by a
>   carriage-return character ('\r'), a
>   newline character ('\n'), a
>   carriage-return character immediately
>   followed by a newline character, or
>   the end of the file.

If the expected text is not found, then you can use one of the write methods of [RandomAccessFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), e.g. [writeUTF()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) or [writeBytes()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeBytes%28java.lang.String%29) to add the line of text to the file.

Comment: But if I went and used readLine() wouldn't it just read the first line, then terminate?

Comment: remember: the lines are like this:

one

two

three

etc.


As far as I can understand, the search stops whenever there's a linebreak..

How do I specify which line to use readLine() on? The method doesn't take any arguments. 

Thank you for your input :).

Comment: Aaah...

I just read the javadoc that you linked.. seems that readLine() reads the next line. Does this mean that each time, regardless of where, just as long as it's in the same stream (e.g. it can be in a for loop in the stream?) it will call the next line?

Comment: That is correct, Mike. A call to readLine() advances the file pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You basically first have to scan parts of or the whole, file for the word you are looking for and then append the word if it doesn't exist.

You could use `readLine()`, however if you don't mind a third party lib you might try [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
File theFile = ...
String theWord = ...

String text = Files.toString(theFile, "utf-8");
if (!text.contains(theWord)) {
   Files.append(theWord,  theFile, "utf-8")
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that I won't be able to use 3rd party libraries in this case :/ thanks for the input

Comment: @Mike, The approach is still the same, only a little more verbose

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a loop and read the text file line by line? After the loop, if you didn't find the line, append it to the end of the file.